# Operator overloading and type casting

Tags: c++, types, casting, operators, overloading

Suppose we have class name Default that have two attribute x and y.
The default operation to compare object is using attribute x.

When we would like to compare this object using other attribute y,
**1. Is it safe to create new derive class that can compare by using attribute y and then casting pointer from Default to that new class and compare object?

2. What is alternative way to do this without decreasing the performance of operation?**

The requirement is we can not change the the signature of sorting algorithm to pass on function pointer to difference comparator.

By the way this method is required no cost for convert or copy data.

```c++
class Default {public:int x; int y;};

class Compare1 : public Default {};

bool operator < (const Default  &left,const Default &right)
{
    return left.x < right.x;
}
bool operator < (const Compare1  &left,const Compare1 &right)
{
    return left.y < right.y;
}

template<typename T>
int *sort_element(const T *data, int size)
{
    int *permute;
    //... do some sorting by using < comparator ...
    return permute;
}

int main(){
    Default *obj;
    int obj_size;
    //… initialize obj and obj size..

    // sorting object with default order.
    int *output_default = sort_element(obj, obj_size)

    // sorting with customize comparator.
    Compare1 *custom1 = static_cast<Compare1*>(obj);
    int *output_custom1 = sort_element(custom1, obj_size);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Better is passing a functor or lambda as compare function when you're sorting them. Your sort function must accept a function:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
int *sort_element(const T *data, int size, F comp)
{

    ....

    if (comp(a, b))
       ....

    ...
}
```

Then

```
// Sort by x
sort_element(..., [](const Default &a, const Default &b) {
      return a.x < b.x;
  });

// Sort by y
sort_element(..., [](const Default &a, const Default &b) {
      return a.y < b.y;
  });
```

If you haven't C++11 you can use function object (functor) instead:

```
struct fx
{
    bool operator()(const Default &a, const Default &b) const
    {
        return a.x < b.x;
    }
};

struct fy
{
    bool operator()(const Default &a, const Default &b) const
    {
        return a.y < b.y;
    }
};

// Sort by x
sort_element(..., fx());

// Sort by x
sort_element(..., fy());
```

Forget your second class `Compare1` and Remove it.

Comment: That sound nice but there is a case that i can't change the header of function sort_element.

Comment: If you can not then unfortunately you have no choice, your code is the only option then you should stop worrying about efficiency.